# ansi-term scroll problem on fast output

Tags: ansi-term, term, scrolling

I use a terminal from within Emacs via `M-x RET ansi-term RET`. The problem is that when I run a program which echoes a lot of output, ansi-term first scrolls with the output (such that the last line of the echoed output is always at the bottom of the terminal) but the scrolling often "breaks" such that ansi-term stops scrolling with the echoed output - i.e. I am looking at some line where scrolling "broke" and there is a lot of new output that I don't see unless I press `C-n` which puts me to the newest echoed line. But then the scrolling breaks again soon... Does anybody know how to fix this? I can provide any debug output you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by myself. Just needed to add the following lines to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
(eval-after-load "term"
  '(progn
     ;; ensure that scrolling doesn't break on output
     (setq term-scroll-to-bottom-on-output t)))
```